# How to determine the location of knots of the restricted cubic spline produced by rcs() of the RMS package?

Tags: r

I am developing a prediction model in R. It uses the restricted cubic spline of an important continuous predictor that is a priori likely to have a nonlinear relationship to the outcome. To do this I used `rms::rcs()` and specified the number of knots, but allowed `rcs()` to 'decide' the location.

I want to extract the coefficients for all the predictors to use in an external application, the purpose of which is to predict *Y* given new input data. However, to do this I need to be able to find the location of the knots that were used by `rcs()`.

The relevant code within `rcs()` is

```
   if (!length(knots)) {
    xd <- rcspline.eval(x, nk = nknots, inclx = TRUE, pc = pc, 
        fractied = fractied)
    knots <- attr(xd, "knots")
}
```

In my case, `pc == 0` and `fractied == 0.05`

How can I find the location of the knots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rms::specs(model) will provide the knots locations for the splines.

Answer (score 2):

A different and better approach is the built in `Function()` function that provides the equation for the fitted model along with all the knot locations.

Answer (score 0):

As hinted in the question, the one possible way to accomplish this is to run `rcspline.evel()` with the predictor and relevant parameters set to those that were used in the model fitting procedure. An example would be

```
rcspline.eval(
     data.frame$predictor,
     nk = number_of_knots_used,
     inclx = TRUE,
     pc = 0, # what ever was used
     fractied = 0.05 # what ever was used
 )
```

The output of this contains `attr(, "knots")` which gives the location of the knots.